# Tenho um relatório em excel, como faço para extrair por data?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um relatório em excel que faz uma pesquisa no BD e traz todas as informações.

como eu faço para colocar no formulário em php o usuário informar a data e pesquisar no BD apenas entre essas datas e montar o excel?

meu cód está assim:

```
 $arquivo = 'relatorio_de_vendas_geral.xls';
 $tabela = '<table border="1">';
 $tabela .= '<tr>';
 $tabela .= '</tr>';
 $tabela .= '<tr>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Cliente</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Usuário</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Data</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Objeto</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Entrega</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Produto</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Quantidade</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Unitário</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Total</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Frete</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Frete Real</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>NF</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Local</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Forma de Pagamento</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Observação</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>ID do Registro</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '</tr>';
 $resultado = mysql_query("
SELECT 
  c.id,
  c.clienteVa cliente,
  c.userml,
  c.dtConcat,
  c.rastreador,
  c.entrega,
  c.nf,
  c.tipo_pagto,
  c.descricao,
  c.frete,
  c.frete_real,
  c.origem,
  p.nome,
  d.valor_unid,
  d.qtd,
  d.valor_total
FROM 
  `lc_controle` c
INNER JOIN `lc_detalhe` d
  ON d.controle_id = c.id
INNER JOIN `lc_cat` p
  ON p.id = d.cat_id  
WHERE
  c.ano = 2017  AND
  c.tipo = 0    AND
  c.clienteAt = 0
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
  c.id,
  cli.nome cliente,
  c.userml,
  c.dtConcat,
  c.rastreador,
  c.entrega,
  c.nf,
  c.tipo_pagto,
  c.descricao,
  c.frete,
  c.frete_real,
  c.origem,
  p.nome,
  d.valor_unid,
  d.qtd,
  d.valor_total
FROM 
  `lc_controle` c
INNER JOIN `lc_detalhe` d
  ON d.controle_id = c.id
INNER JOIN `lc_cat` p
  ON p.id = d.cat_id
INNER JOIN `clientes` cli
  ON cli.id = c.clienteAt     
WHERE
  c.ano = 2017  AND
  c.tipo = 0    AND
  c.clienteAt <> 0
  ORDER BY dtConcat ASC
");
 while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
 {
  $tabela .= '<tr>';
  $tabela .= '<td>'.$dados['cliente'].'</td>';
  $tabela .= '<td>'.$dados['userml'].'</td>';
  $tabela .= '<td>'.$dados["dtConcat"];
  $tabela .= '<td>'.$dados['rastreador'].'</td>';
  $tabela .= '<td>'.$dados['entrega'].'</td>';
  $tabela .= '<td>'.$dados['nome'].'</td>';
  $tabela .= '<td>'.$dados['qtd'].'</td>';
  $tabela .= '<td>'.$dados['valor_unid'] = number_format($dados['valor_unid'], 2, ',', '.').'</td>';
  $tabela .= '<td>'.$dados['valor_total'] = number_format($dados['valor_total'], 2, ',', '.').'</td>';
  $tabela .= '<td>'.$dados['frete'] = number_format($dados['frete'], 2, ',', '.').'</td>';
  $tabela .= '<td>'.$dados['frete_real'] = number_format($dados['frete_real'], 2, ',', '.').'</td>';
  $tabela .= '<td>'.$dados['nf'].'</td>';
  $tabela .= '<td>'.$dados['origem'].'</td>';
  $tabela .= '<td>'.$dados['tipo_pagto'].'</td>';
  $tabela .= '<td>'.$dados['descricao'].'</td>';
  $tabela .= '<td>'.$dados['id'].'</td>';
  $tabela .= '</tr>';
 }
 $tabela .= '</table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver a questão, você deve ter, em seu formulário, campos para informar o período:

Feito isso, receba esses campos no PHP e acrescente na sua query:

"... and dtConcat between '$datainicial' and '$dataFinal'"

**Não se esqueça de converter a data recebida em um formato válido para o tipo de campo na sua tabela.**

Minha resposta se baseia na possibilidade de seu campo de data ser do tipo Date ou Timestamp.

**Uma dica bastante válida**

Não use mysql_query. Prefira usar a lib mysqli ou PDO, por medida de segurança do seu programa.